# Maximum Product Subarray GFG Question Python

Tags: python

I was practising DSA questions.

Given an array Arr[] that contains N integers (may be positive, negative or zero). Find the product of the maximum product subarray.

I am unable to complete this code. Please check the code and help. Thanks in advance.

```
def maxSubarrayProduct(arr, n):
  
        result = arr[0]
  
        for i in range(n):
      
            mul = arr[i]
        
            for j in range(i + 1, n):
          
                result = max(result, mul)
                mul *= arr[j]
          
            result = max(result, mul)
      
        return result
```

Comment: Please mention the input and output you are expecting in your question

Comment: DSA tag is for digital signature algorithm. Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the program you wrote comes under brute force methods which have the worst time complexity. To improve its time and space complexity you can just make 2 variables that will store your current max and current min value. Here is the code for reference. Happy coding. Let me know if this helps.

```
def maxProduct(self,arr, n):
        res = max(arr)
        currMax, currMin = 1,1
        
        for i in arr:
            if i == 0:
                currMax, currMin = 1,1
                continue
            #Storing max value to use it later on.
            temp = currMax*i
            currMax = max(currMax*i, currMin*i, i)
            currMin = min(currMin*i, temp, i)
            
            res = max(res, currMax)
        
        return res
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you very much. Can you please explain use of max() and min(). Sorry I am a newbie in python. I dont know much about it. Thanks

Comment: max() and min() are used to find max value and minimum value in all of the 3 above. Like if you use max(1, 3) so the output will be 3 and vice versa. Let me know if you need any further explanation. Most welcome.

Comment: @Pratul Pant : Can you share the input you pass to the script

Comment: I tried on gfg console as he mentioned. Here is the link.

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-product-subarray3604/1?page=1&difficulty[]=1&category[]=Arrays&sortBy=submissions